# Linking an external LDAP directory with a local LDAP directory

Tags: ldap, openldap

I developed a intranet portal  with an external LDAP directory for authentication. I only have read permission on this LDAP directory (I can neither modify it nor replicate it). I would like to link the users of this external LDAP to an LDAP I will have created for to create groups and subgroups for example. In addition, I would like it to remain transparent for the portal. What would be the best solutions?

Comment: you might want to detail what web application is written in so people can help you tailor answers based on the framework you're using.

Comment: There are numerous solutions, starting with the `translucent` backend, and they are all off topic.